# Determine the Unit Impulse Response of ARMA Filter for 8 First Indices

Tags: signal-analysis, impulse-response

I have this problem, I've checked for almost 3 hours in books and internet for the unit impulse response for n = 0 : 7 but nothing. 
[image: Test]

I've benn working on how to get h[t] but I end up on a dead end at:

[[image: Test[2]]

From there, I don't know how to solve this problem, Someone could help me pls?

Comment: Maybe if you tried working the problem instead of searching in books and the Internet to see if the answer is available already, your question would get more respect. -1 for "This question does not show any effort."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote correctly the function is given by:

$$ y \left[ n \right] = \frac{1}{2} y \left[ n - 1 \right] + \frac{1}{8} y \left[ n - 2 \right] + \frac{1}{2} x \left[ n - 2 \right] $$

Assuming initial conditions of 0 we can easily see that for unit impulse (Namely all zeros but $ x \left[ 0 \right] = 1 $:

$$ \begin{align*}
y \left[ 0 \right] & = 0 \\
y \left[ 1 \right] & = 0 \\
y \left[ 2 \right] & = \frac{1}{2} \\
y \left[ 3 \right] & = 0.5 * y \left[ 2 \right] = \frac{1}{4} \\
y \left[ 4 \right] & = 0.5 * y \left[ 3 \right] + 0.125 * y \left[ 2 \right] = \frac{3}{16} \\
y \left[ 5 \right] & = 0.5 * y \left[ 4 \right] + 0.125 * y \left[ 3 \right] = 
\frac{1}{8} \\
y \left[ 6 \right] & = 0.5 * y \left[ 5 \right] + 0.125 * y \left[ 4 \right] = \frac{11}{128} \\
y \left[ 7 \right] & = 0.5 * y \left[ 6 \right] + 0.125 * y \left[ 5 \right] = \frac{15}{256} \\
\end{align*}
$$

Since it has IIR Component it will go on infinitely.

MATLAB Simulation:

[image]

The full code can be found in my [StackExchange Signal Processing Q43918 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\Q43918` folder).